# Removing vertical scroll from a page using bootstrap 5 responsive design

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, responsive

I am converting a Figma design to an HTML page and using Bootstrap 5. Here's how the Figma design looks:

[image]

The issue is that I am getting a vertical scroll bar on the page. The following highlighted space in the red box is causing it.

[image]

The image height inside the `col` div does not force it to vertically overflow. How is the column height being set?

[image]

I have tried setting the height of the image div, but then it makes the image height really small. I do not want to change the height of the class manually. What I want to know is how is the div height being set when I am using responsive row/col classes.

Here's the code I've done:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  h4 {
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .left-col {
    padding-top: 200px;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    background-color: #f0efff;
    height: 62px;
  }
  input[type="text"]:focus {
    background-color: #f0efff;
    border-radius: 10%;
  }
  input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    color: #a7a3ff !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  input::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #a7a3ff !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* IE 10+ */
    color: #a7a3ff !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  input:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #a7a3ff !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  a {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .continue-with {
    font-size: 16px;
    clear: #b5b5b5;
  }
  .btn-login {
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .btn-round {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .btn-round img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
  .image {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10%;
    height: 75%;
    right: 5%;
  }
  .right-col {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  .btn-primary {
    background-color: #4d47c3 !important;
  }
  .text-primary {
    color: #4d47c3 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Login 1</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="./login-1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body style="height: 100vh">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a style="font-weight: bold" class="navbar-brand text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Your logo</a
        >
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container px-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 left-col">
          <div class="row mb-4">
            <div class="col">
              <h1 style="font-weight: bold" class="py-2">Sign in to</h1>
              <h4 style="font-size: 35px">Lorem Ipsum is simply</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row py-4">
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="pt-2" style="font-size: 16px">
                If you don’t have an account register.<br />
                You can
                <span class="text-primary" style="font-weight: bold"
                  >Register here!</span
                >
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <img
                src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaslam94/figma-exercises/main/login-1/assets/images/saly-14.png"
                alt="image"
                class="image"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 right-col">
          <h4 class="mb-4">Sign in</h4>
          <form>
            <div class="mb-4">
              <input
                class="form-control px-3 border-0"
                type="text"
                name="Email"
                placeholder="Enter email or user name"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="mb-2">
              <input
                class="form-control px-3 mb-2 border-0"
                type="text"
                name="Password"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
              <a
                href="#"
                class="text-decoration-none form-text float-end"
                style="color: #b5b5b5"
                >Forgot Password?</a
              >
            </div>

            <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-5">
              <input
                type="submit"
                value="Login"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-login shadow-lg"
              />
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="form-text continue-with text-center py-5">
            or continue with
          </div>
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-auto p-1">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-round">
                <img
                  src="/login-1/assets/logos/facebook-icon.png"
                  alt="Facebook Icon"
                />
              </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto p-1">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-round">
        <img src="/login-1/assets/logos/apple-icon.png" alt="Apple Icon" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto p-1">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-round">
        <img src="/login-1/assets/logos/google-icon.png" alt="Google Icon" />
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Check on CodePen: https://codepen.io/junaidaslam/pen/WNYRRzK?editors=1100

Comment: In the `<body style="height: 100vh">` tag you have hard coded the height of the screen, kindly remove it and check the reflection

Comment: @lareb Removed `style="height: 100vh"`  from the `body` tag but it did not affect the scroll bar.

Comment: write `<body>` instead of `<body style="height: 100vh">`.
Just remove the style tag from the body.

Comment: @lareb Yeah, I meant I removed style from the body tag. I have updated my comment. I have also attached the link to the CodePen of this. You can check that as well.

Comment: I am also attaching the code in the Answers until kindly remove the `left-col` and `right-col` classes from the divs from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try the following.
<div class="container px-5">
   <div class="row justify-content-around align-items-center" style="
      height: 90vh;
      ">
      <div class="col-md-8 left-col">
         <div class="mb-4">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold;" class="py-2">Sign in to</h1>
            <h4 style="font-size: 35px;">Lorem Ipsum is simply</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="d-flex py-4">
            <div class="pt-2" style="font-size: 16px;">
               If you don’t have an account register.<br>
               You can
               <span class="text-primary" style="font-weight: bold;">Register here!</span>
            </div>
            <div>
               <img src="/assets/images/saly-14.png" alt="image" class="" style="
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 395px;
                  width: 15%;
                  ">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 right-col">
         <h4 class="mb-4">Sign in</h4>
         <form>
            <div class="mb-4 form-group">
               <input class="form-control px-3 border-0" type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Enter email or user name">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 form-group">
               <input class="form-control px-3 border-0" type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-5 form-group text-end"><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none ">Forgot Password?</a></div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-login w-100">
            </div>
         </form>
         <div class="form-text continue-with text-center py-5">
            or continue with
         </div>
         <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-auto p-1">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-round">
               <img src="/assets/logos/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook Icon">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto p-1">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-round">
               <img src="/assets/logos/apple-icon.png" alt="Apple Icon">
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto p-1">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-round">
               <img src="/assets/logos/google-icon.png" alt="Google Icon">
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly consider this code, I have removed `left-col` and `right-col` padding from the code, which is consuming the space and generating the scroll.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap");

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;

  h4 {
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .left-col {
    // padding-top: 200px;
  }

  input[type="text"] {
    background-color: #f0efff;
    height: 62px;
  }

  input[type="text"]:focus {
    background-color: #f0efff;
    border-radius: 10%;
  }

  input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    color: #a7a3ff !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  input::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #a7a3ff !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* IE 10+ */
    color: #a7a3ff !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
  input:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #a7a3ff !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }

  a {
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  .continue-with {
    font-size: 16px;
    clear: #b5b5b5;
  }

  .btn-login {
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .btn-round {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .btn-round img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }

  .image {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10%;
    height: 75%;
    right: 5%;
  }

  .right-col {
    // padding-top: 100px;
    // padding-bottom: 100px;
  }

  .btn-primary {
    background-color: #4d47c3 !important;
  }

  .text-primary {
    color: #4d47c3 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Login 1</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="./login-1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a style="font-weight: bold" class="navbar-brand text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Your logo</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container px-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bold" class="py-2">Sign in to</h1>
            <h4 style="font-size: 35px">Lorem Ipsum is simply</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-4">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="pt-2" style="font-size: 16px">
              If you don’t have an account register.<br />
              You can
              <span class="text-primary" style="font-weight: bold">Register here!</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaslam94/figma-exercises/main/login-1/assets/images/saly-14.png" alt="image" class="image" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 class="mb-4">Sign in</h4>
        <form>
          <div class="mb-4">
            <input class="form-control px-3 border-0" type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Enter email or user name" />
          </div>

          <div class="mb-2">
            <input class="form-control px-3 mb-2 border-0" type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password" />
            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none form-text float-end" style="color: #b5b5b5">Forgot Password?</a>
          </div>

          <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-5">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-login shadow-lg" />
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="form-text continue-with text-center py-5">
          or continue with
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-auto p-1">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-round">
              <img src="/login-1/assets/logos/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook Icon" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto p-1">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-round">
              <img src="/login-1/assets/logos/apple-icon.png" alt="Apple Icon" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto p-1">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-round">
              <img src="/login-1/assets/logos/google-icon.png" alt="Google Icon" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue as now the space between the "Sign in to" heading and the top navbar is gone. The vertical scroll bar is also still visible. You can check here: https://codepen.io/junaidaslam/pen/WNYRRzK?editors=1100

Comment: it is working correctly, as if you write this code other then the codepen editor as the is a header nav bar on the top of the page which is causing the scroll, further more try this css additionally:
`
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  .image {
    position: relative;
    // bottom: 10%;
    // height: 75%;
    right: 5%;
    display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 100%;
  }
`

Comment: With due respect, it is not working correctly. You can look at the page in full screen on CodePen as well. Applying `overflow: hidden;` to the body tag removes the scroll bar on the xl screen but makes it unresponsive on smaller screens. The classes `left-col` and `right-col` are also needed, they are only setting the padding based on the original design. The position of the image also needs to be set. Kindly take a look at the original Figma design in my post.